# $\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)} dx = 1$. How?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)} dx = 1$$. How?

I can do

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)} dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}{(x)} \; dx$$ But how do I proceed? I remember the TA mentioning something about changing the limits of integration to $\pi/2$ but I don't really understand why ...

Comment: The TA is talking about substitution. Or you could just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus directly.

Comment: To start with, $1-x^2$ should be corrected to $1+x^2$. Then draw the graph of $\tan^{-1}x$. What does this function tend to for $x\rightarrow \infty$? $-\infty$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^n \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\tan^{-1}(x)\right]_{-n}^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}[\tan^{-1}(n)-\tan^{-1}(-n)]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2\tan^{-1}(n)=\pi
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi(x) = \arctan x$, then $\tan \phi(x) = x$ and differentiating gives $\frac{1}{\cos^2 \phi(x)} \phi'(x) = 1$. This gives $\phi'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Then $\int_0^x \phi'(t) dt = \phi(x)-\phi(0)$. Taking limits gives $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt = \frac{\pi}{2}$.